# How to fetch maximum value from logs

Tags: text-processing

I have log file which shows ten values and last column value is memory in bytes. If I wanted to display highest memory used in last four days, what command or script should I use? With the help of `curl` or `awk` command how do I get the max memory value used in last four days?

The log file's name is `ansh.log`, and it contains the following:

```
 Timestamp ,xyz=1, abc=2, def=6 ,memory=64357890
Timestamp ,xyz=1 ,abc =2 , def =6 , memory=64987201
```

Now I want last column (`memory`) highest value . I have last four days log lines in this log file so it is very big file.

Comment: Regarding `With the help of curl or awk command` - how could `curl` play a part in this?

Answer (score 5):

Since we're only looking for the max value, we don't need to sort, just scan through the file:

```bsh
awk -F "=" '
    $NF > max {max = $NF}
    END {print max}
' ansh.log
```

If you love a one-liner

```bsh
awk -F= '$NF > max {max = $NF} END {print max}' ansh.log
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get it with sed/cut/awk as you prefer to separate it & then sort answers with displaying only the last one then you got the highest one

example with many sub commands to be easier to read:

```
$
 cat > /tmp/a #define a fake-file for test/demo
Timestamp ,xyz=1, abc=2, def=6 ,memory=64357890 Timestamp ,xyz=1 ,abc =2 , def =6 , memory=64987201
Timestamp ,xyz=1, abc=2, def=6 ,memory=64357890 Timestamp ,xyz=1 ,abc =2 , def =6 , memory=64987555
Timestamp ,xyz=1, abc=2, def=6 ,memory=64357890 Timestamp ,xyz=1 ,abc =2 , def =6 , memory=64798797
Timestamp ,xyz=1, abc=2, def=6 ,memory=64357890 Timestamp ,xyz=1 ,abc =2 , def =6 , memory=64911111
Timestamp ,xyz=1, abc=2, def=6 ,memory=64357890 Timestamp ,xyz=1 ,abc =2 , def =6 , memory=61111111
$
  sed "s/ Time/\nTime/1 ; s/.*=//" /tmp/a | sort -n | tail -1 # one line for each timestamp even we have many on same line / then get only number / then sort numbers / then keep only the last one (higher cause they are sorted)
64987555 
$
 variable=$(sed "s/ Time/\nTime/1 ; s/.*=//" /tmp/a | sort -n | tail -1)  # if your want that in a variable only
$
 echo ${variable}
64987555
$
 rm /tmp/a  # remove test-file
```

Answer (score 3):

Since @glennjackman already has the awk script covered, here's an alternative that's actually pretty concise and efficient assuming you always have 4 `=`s on each line as shown in your sample input:

```
$ cut -d'=' -f5 file | sort -rn | head -1
64987201
```

If you have variable numbers of `=` you could always replace that `cut` command with `awk -F'=' '{print $NF}'`.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne 'state @a.push(.match: /<?after memory\= > <digit>+ $/ ); END put @a.max;'
```

Sample Input:

```
Timestamp, xyz=1, abc=2, def=6, memory=64357890
Timestamp, xyz=1, abc=2, def=6, memory=64987201
```

Sample Output:

```
64987201
```

Above a solution is coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages.

Briefly, `raku` is run at the command line with the `-ne` (linewise, non-autoprinting) flags. An array `@a` is `state`-d and immediately has values `push`-ed upon it. The values `push`-ed upon it are one-or-more `<digit>+`-s captured in the `match` operation. The `match` operation employs Raku's zero-width positive lookbehind construct `<?after ... >`.  A `?` (positive) `match` is demanded `after` the escaped string `memory\=`. The entire  lookbehind reads as follows:  `<?after memory\= >`. At the `END` of linewise operations, the `max` of values in `@a` are `put` (printed-using-terminator).

There are simpler ways to code this solution such as comparing each value to a preceding value and keeping the `max` in every case. However this solution has the advantage that all `memory` values are extracted and held in `@a` for later use, such as for statistical analysis (e.g. mean).

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one similar to Ed Morton answer but this doesn't require a fixed number of `=`:

```
grep -oh "memory.[0-9,=]*" file | cut -d'=' -f2 | sort -rn | head -1
```